# Label Put Before Center AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to put a label just before center.

I am unable to do this and i am unable to find any link how we do this.I am newer in iOS. I am unable to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: upload your code and your storyboard UI and then give you answer

Comment: I have no much reputation to upload image

Comment: just before center means

Comment: in your question you can add image . try it

Comment: It means just label text end before 1 point in center

Comment: your question i cant understand what you want .

Comment: take screenshot from simulator and upload image here

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a UILabel to you view that is aligned with its rightmost part on the horizontal centre of the view?

Comment: yes sir end just before center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to do the following

- Center the UILabel Horizontally with the View Controller's view
- Open the constraint and change label.Center X to label.Trailing

[image]

Comment: Better: create the "Center Horizontally" constraint. Then edit the constraint and change the label end from "Center" to "Trailing". No need to know the width of the label.